# How to merge/split multiple spans of dates into one timeline (Oracle 11g)?

Tags: oracle, date

I've been wrestling with this problem for a few days and now I am turning to the masses for help.

My problem is similar, but not quite the same, as a previous solution on this site:
[PL/SQL Split, separate a date into new dates according to black out dates!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252976/pl-sql-split-separate-a-date-into-new-dates-according-to-black-out-dates)
This solution is rather boolean (include/exclude) whereas my issue involves some of that as well as merging.

While I like to think I have an intermediate/advanced grasp on SQL+PL/SQL ... Oracle Analytic functions apparently boggle my mind.  I've been trying to read/learn but I'm running out of time.

As I'm not sure of the legality of sharing table names (COTS), line of business and such, I'm going to mimic my issue with a vague-er scenario/context.  Hopefully that will ward off the lawyer spirits.

On to the problem:
I have a table that houses a customer's activity history.  The customer can come and go and so we may have multiple rows in this table (per customer).

```
CREATE TABLE activity AS
SELECT 1 AS cust_id,
       TO_DATE('01-JAN-2010') AS start_dt,
       TO_DATE('31-JUL-2010') AS end_dt,
       'EAST' AS region
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1 AS cust_id,
       TO_DATE('01-FEB-2011') AS start_dt,
       TO_DATE('31-DEC-2011') AS end_dt,
       'EAST' AS region
FROM DUAL;
```

I also have a table that houses attribute information by span.  A customer could have multiple attribute types at once and each type multiple times for varying timespans.

```
CREATE TABLE attrib AS
SELECT 1 AS cust_id,
       'POWER' AS atb_cd,
       TO_DATE('01-JAN-2009') AS atb_start_dt,
       TO_DATE('31-JAN-2010') AS atb_end_dt,
       'LocalNuke' AS provider,
       1.80 AS per_kwh,
       0 AS per_gal
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1 AS cust_id,
       'POWER' AS atb_cd,
       TO_DATE('01-MAR-2010') AS atb_start_dt,
       TO_DATE('31-MAR-2010') AS atb_end_dt,
       'CoalGuys' AS provider,
       1.60 AS per_kwh,
       0 AS per_gal
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1 AS cust_id,
       'POWER' AS atb_cd,
       TO_DATE('01-JUN-2010') AS atb_start_dt,
       TO_DATE('30-SEP-2010') AS atb_end_dt,
       'LocalNuke' AS provider,
       1.70 AS per_kwh,
       0 AS per_gal
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1 AS cust_id,
       'POWER' AS atb_cd,
       TO_DATE('01-MAR-2011') AS atb_start_dt,
       TO_DATE('31-DEC-9999') AS atb_end_dt,
       'GeoHeat' AS provider,
       1.10 AS per_kwh,
       0 AS per_gal
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1 AS cust_id,
       'WATER' AS atb_cd,
       TO_DATE('01-MAR-2010') AS atb_start_dt,
       TO_DATE('31-DEC-9999') AS atb_end_dt,
       'GlacialGold' AS provider,
       0 AS per_kwh,
       0.60 AS per_gal
FROM DUAL;
```

The data oddities are intentional, I tried to make this scenario as real-world as I could  without being related to "the real world".

The result should constrain the spans to the customers' activity with this fictitious company and split out all of the overlapping dates to form a timeline.  Data-elements will need to be merged together for reporting.

Visually:

```
Cust:
         |----------------------|             |------------------------|
Power:
|-------------|    |--|    |-------|               |---------------------->
Water:
                   |------------------------------------------------------>    
Expected Result:
         |----|----|--|----|----|             |----|-------------------|
```

The solution should be scalable to include other attributes as well.  At the end, I'd have this denormalized info in a table so I could report a customer's data at any point in time.  For instance, if they had activity, power and water on a particular day; I should be able to export the per_kwh, per_gal and activity data for that day.

Example Output (Tabular):

```
CUST_ID  FROM_DT      THRU_DT      REGION  POWER_PROVIDER  WATER_PROVIDER  PER_KWH  PER_GAL
-------  -----------  -----------  ------  --------------  --------------  -------  -------
1        01-JAN-2010  31-JAN-2010  EAST    LocalNuke                       1.80     0
1        01-FEB-2010  28-FEB-2010  EAST                                    0        0
1        01-MAR-2010  31-MAR-2010  EAST    CoalGuys        GlacialGold     1.60     0.60
1        01-APR-2010  31-MAY-2010  EAST                    GlacialGold     0        0.60
1        01-JUN-2010  31-JUL-2010  EAST    LocalNuke       GlacialGold     1.70     0.60
1        01-FEB-2011  28-FEB-2011  EAST                    GlacialGold     0        0.60
1        01-MAR-2011  31-DEC-2011  EAST    GeoHeat         GlacialGold     1.10     0.60
```

I wrote something about 2 years ago (when the requirement was akin to just Activity/Power) using 2 asynchronous cursors processing slow-by-slow (row-by-row).

While performance is important, the biggest reason why I'm trying to find a straight/bulk sql solution is maintainance.  The if/else cursor nesting of my original solution is already difficult to follow and will be exponentially worse with at least 2 more "attribute" spans to split on.

I would be grateful for any and all help any of you may be able to provide.

Comment: Can you post the output of the query you'd want?  The visual is helpful but I'm not sure I understand how to translate the visual to some sort of tabular query result.

Comment: Question modified to include expected tabular output - recommended by @JustinCave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work. It doesn't merge contiguous regions together, but it should still get the job done.

```
WITH

  milestone AS
  (
    SELECT cust_id, start_dt     AS point_in_time FROM ACTIVITY
  UNION
    SELECT cust_id, atb_start_dt AS point_in_time FROM ATTRIB
  UNION
    SELECT cust_id, LEAST(end_dt,     TO_DATE('30-DEC-9999')) + 1 AS point_in_time FROM ACTIVITY
  UNION
    SELECT cust_id, LEAST(atb_end_dt, TO_DATE('30-DEC-9999')) + 1 AS point_in_time FROM ATTRIB
  )

SELECT
  milestone.cust_id                 AS cust_id,
  milestone.point_in_time           AS from_dt,
  LEAD(point_in_time)
    OVER (PARTITION BY milestone.cust_id ORDER BY milestone.point_in_time) - 1
                                    AS thru_dt,
  activity.region                   AS region,
  power_attrib.provider             AS power_provider,
  water_attrib.provider             AS water_provider,
  COALESCE(power_attrib.per_kwh, 0) AS per_kwh,
  COALESCE(water_attrib.per_gal, 0) AS per_gal
FROM
  MILESTONE

  LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY
    ON milestone.cust_id = activity.cust_id
       AND milestone.point_in_time BETWEEN activity.start_dt AND activity.end_dt

  LEFT OUTER JOIN ATTRIB power_attrib
    ON milestone.cust_id = power_attrib.cust_id
       AND power_attrib.atb_cd = 'POWER'
       AND milestone.point_in_time BETWEEN power_attrib.atb_start_dt AND power_attrib.atb_end_dt

  LEFT OUTER JOIN ATTRIB water_attrib
    ON milestone.cust_id = water_attrib.cust_id
       AND water_attrib.atb_cd = 'WATER'
       AND milestone.point_in_time BETWEEN water_attrib.atb_start_dt AND water_attrib.atb_end_dt
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!  I'm going to need some time to understand/disect and apply your feedback.  I'll update later with results and (if successful) award answer(s).

Comment: This is looking very promising.  I've re-written it for my system and had to tweak a few things (didn't want the non-active rows).  I still would like to do a bit more testing tomorrow before I approve the answer (a.k.a. while I still hopefully have your attention).  Your solution is so straight forward (elegant) I want to kick myself in the shin!

Comment: @Brock: Glad to be of help. :) I had to solve this just the other day.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a very rticky problem, and I expect you'll end up with a big messy query. The core problem you have is you need to manufacture "psudeo" rows for the gaps in the attrib table. This is problematic.

I took a cutdown version of your problem, just trying to manufacture the gaps for the POWER attrib. I took the attidute that every attrib row can be preceded by a gap. Came up with this

```
SELECT  PS.cust_id
    ,   G.is_gap
    ,   DECODE( G.is_gap, 'Y', PS.prev_start, PS.atb_start_dt ) AS start_date
    ,   DECODE( G.is_gap, 'Y', PS.prev_end, PS.atb_end_dt ) AS end_date
    ,   DECODE( G.is_gap, 'Y', NULL, PS.provider ) AS provider
    ,   DECODE( G.is_gap, 'Y', NULL, PS.per_kwh ) AS per_kwh
    ,   DECODE( G.is_gap, 'Y', NULL, PS.per_gal ) AS per_gal
FROM
    (   SELECT  P.cust_id
            ,   P.atb_start_dt
            ,   P.atb_end_dt
            ,   P.provider
            ,   P.per_kwh
            ,   P.per_gal
            ,   P.atb_start_dt - 1      AS prev_end
            ,   NVL( MAX( P.atb_end_dt ) OVER ( ORDER BY P.atb_end_dt
                        ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ) + 1
                   , '01-JAN-1900' )    AS prev_start
        FROM    attrib      P
        WHERE   P.atb_cd    = 'POWER'
    ) PS
,   (   SELECT  DECODE(LEVEL,1,'Y','N') AS is_gap
        FROM    DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
    ) G
WHERE   (   PS.prev_end > PS.prev_start
        OR  G.is_gap    = 'N' )
ORDER BY 3
/
```

Gave me these results

```
CUST_ID I START_DATE END_DATE   PROVIDER    PER_KWH PER_GAL
------- - ---------- ---------- ----------- ------- -------
      1 Y 01-JAN-00  31-DEC-08
      1 N 01-JAN-09  31-JAN-10  LocalNuke   1.8     0
      1 N 01-FEB-10  31-MAR-10  CoalGuys    1.6     0
      1 Y 01-APR-10  31-MAY-10
      1 N 01-JUN-10  30-SEP-10  LocalNuke   1.7     0
      1 Y 01-OCT-10  28-FEB-11
      1 N 01-MAR-11  31-DEC-99  GeoHeat     1.1     0
```

Some notes:

- I think row 5 of your sample results has an incorrect end date. Should it be `31-JUL-2010` because thats when the `activity` ends?
- I updated the `CoalGuys` start date to `01-FEB-2010` to test when there was no gap
- Will be screwed if there is no activity which runs to the distant future because it does not generate a trailing gap, just a preceeding one. Could always `UNION` one in I guess
- Better no to use `9999` as a year as you get errors if you try and add anything to it. Didn't end up mattering, but was a hastle if you go for trailing gaps.

Now this is a long way from the full solution, once you throw in the customer and water dates it gets messier still. But you'll probably need the guts of the above as an inline view to include in the master query. Then you'll have to do the same thing for WATER. Then you'll have to join the two together with date range checks, and then use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` for your final date results.

Sorry, after the 40 or so minutes I've spent on this its gone from an intersting problem to feeling like work, so going to leave my answer incomplete. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the row 5 in my expected output being incorrect.  I will fix it now.It will take me a while to digest and try stuff out ... but I wanted to thank you for providing notes and your thought processes.  Even if your comments don't pan out, they will help me to wrap my head around this new way of thinking for doing stuff with Analytics.